How to insert data that comes from JSON into a table in Oracle APEX
I have an application in Oracle Apex that needs to consume data from a JSON that comes through a webhook, and insert it into my table.
The data is coming in the following structure:
{
  "event_type": "WEBHOOK.MARKED_OPPORTUNITY",
  "entity_type": "CONTACT",
  "event_identifier": "my-event-identifier",
  "timestamp": "2018-03-13T14:09:02.724-03:00",
  "event_timestamp": "2018-03-13T14:07:04.254-03:00",
  "contact": {
    "uuid": "c2f3d2b3-7250-4d27-97f4-eef38be32f7f",
    "email": "support@example.org",
    "name": "Contact Name",
    "job_title": "Developer",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://rdstation.com.br",
    "personal_phone": "48 30252598",
    "mobile_phone": "48 30252598",
    "city": "Florianópolis",
    "facebook": "Contact Facebook",
    "linkedin": "Contact Linkedin",
    "twitter": "Contact Twitter",
    "tags": [
      "tag 1",
      "tag 2"
    ],
    "cf_custom_field_example": [
      "Option1",
      "Option2"
    ],
    "company": {
      "name": "Company Example 0"
    },
    "funnel": {
      "name": "default",
      "lifecycle_stage": "Lead",
      "opportunity": false,
      "contact_owner_email": "owner@example.org",
      "interest": 20,
      "fit": 0,
      "origin": "Orgânico"
    }
  }
}

My question is how do I insert some of this data into my table when I trigger POST?
I'm trying this PL/SQL on my RESTful data services POST method
DECLARE
    new_id INTEGER;
    current_date DATE;
    blob_body BLOB := :body;
    clob_variable CLOB := CONVERT_TO_CLOB(blob_body);
    
    v_name VARCHAR2(100);
    v_email VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT SYSDATE INTO current_date FROM dual;

    DECLARE
        v_json_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
    BEGIN
        v_json_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(clob_variable);
        
        v_name := v_json_obj.get_String('name');
        v_email := v_json_obj.get_String('email');
    END;

    INSERT INTO LEADS (ID, NOME, EMAIL)
    VALUES (121212, v_name, v_email)
    RETURNING ID INTO new_id;

    :status_code := 201;
    :forward_location := '../employees/' || new_id;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        :errmsg := 'Wrong value.';
        :status_code := 400;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        :status_code := 400;
        :errmsg := SQLERRM;
END;

I need to insert name and email value from JSON on my table LEADS.

Does the code you posted throw an error?  What is the error?  What is the code doing that it should not be doing or not doing that it should be doing?

on the platform where I am trying to validate the webhook by sending JSON with the URL of my application, it is giving an error that the server responded with an error

You can do it using JSON_TABLE:
DECLARE
  v_date  DATE := SYSDATE;
  v_id    LEADS.ID%TYPE;
  v_name  LEADS.NOME%TYPE;
  v_email LEADS.EMAIL%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT name, email
  INTO   v_name, v_email
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           :body,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.contact.name',
             email VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.contact.email'
           )
         );

  INSERT INTO LEADS (ID, NOME, EMAIL)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, v_name, v_email)
  RETURNING ID INTO v_id;

  :status_code := 201;
  :forward_location := '../employees/' || v_id;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        :errmsg := 'Wrong value.';
        :status_code := 400;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        :status_code := 400;
        :errmsg := SQLERRM;
END;
/


It works for me, thanks a lot!!
